# Edi-Cam Streaming Video Using Intel Edison Help Needed

Tags: javascript, video, websocket, portforwarding, intel-edison

I am using a USB Webcam attached to an Intel Edison Arduino board running Edi-Cam application to monitor to do security monitoring. I can connect to it from inside of my local network and view the video stream. I want to be able to view the webcam in a browser outside of the my local network. I have added port forwarding through my router and I can view the edi-cam web page but all I see is the 320x200 box and the word Loading...

This is the link to the original project by Esther Jun Kim.
[Edi-Cam Streaming USB Video Project](http://drejkim.com/blog/2014/12/08/video-streaming-on-edison)

I am thinking that this line needs to be changed: var wsUrl = 'ws://edison.local:8084/' because when the page is viewed in a remote browser this line my not be able to reference my edison. What do you think?

Do you have any ideas on how to get the video to appear? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am no networking expert. But you can't just change the wsURL. You are probably going to have to change some settings on the camera and your router with some DNS addresses and port forwarding. If you google "make webcam accessible outside home network" that might help you get started.

Comment: Thanks for you comments. I will google that and post any new info I come across.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to this question with the help of Esther Jun Kim the original programmer of Edi-Cam.

The solution was to port forwarded 8084 to my computers IP address and change the wsUrl to the external IP address of my router. That worked!